# Conda activate test environment not working

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter, conda

[image: Picture of Error I am getting]

What should my next steps be to get my conda activate test back up and working?

I should note that `activate test` works but I dont know why the sudden change.

Comment: Please don't share information as images unless absolutely necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Just do what it says. VS Code uses cmd.exe or Powershell, depending on your settings. Run the `conda init cmd.exe`, test if it works, then run `conda init powershell`.

Comment: thanks for the help, that works when I am in anaconda prompt and I am not getting any errors.

Comment: However when I am opening VS code it is running the test.env and when i run .py files it gives me the same error i was seeing in anaconda prompt. Any idea how to solve issues inside VS code?

Comment: Honestly, just read the Anaconda documentation. VS Code uses cmd or Powershell as it’s console. If you get it running with those, it will work with VS Code

Comment: Don't run the command in Anaconda Prompt but in your normal terminal (it looks like you're using Command Prompt).